# ASP.NET Forms Authentication on Load Balanced Servers

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, load-balancing

Are there any possible issues with using the default Forms Authentication (see below) on Load Balanced servers?  If there can be, what can I do to prevent the issues.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Login/" protection="All" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

Can I use cookies (used by default)?  Do I have to go cookieless? etc...

Also, does Microsoft (or VMWare) have a VirtualPC download that is an instant Load Balanced testing environment?

Comment: On some load balancers there is the idea of a sticky-session that may also be an idea but outside of the web code in ASP.Net

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is one issue. The cookies are encrypted and validated using the machine key and the validation key (that's what *protection="All"* means). You will have to set those in your top-level web.config in all the servers, otherwise each of them will have a different one and will reject cookies set by the others.

You can find a machineKey generator [here](http://developerfusion.com/tools/generatemachinekey). Then put the generated xml inside  in the web.config of all the servers and you're ready to rock.

Comment: I would imagine this link worked at some point, but that URL now points to a domain expiration.

Comment: here's one I used a few minutes ago: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/generatemachinekey/