# Missing asp.net forms authentication cookie

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

We have a bizaar situation. We have the following in our web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms name="ASPDNSFGUID" loginUrl="SignIn.aspx" timeout="525600" /></authentication>
```

This is an ecommerce app, and the cookie is used to help us make sure that the contents of a basket is retained after they login, and this is not working. We've used this dozens of times before without problem.

The site is hosted on two front end web servers sitting behind a coyote point load balancer. We've noticed that when the site is viewed via HTTPS, the cookie is there, the authentication type is forms. HOWEVER, when we browse non-secure, the cookie is missing and the authentication type is not set. We know this because we created a page to print out all the headers for us.

Does anybody have any ideas on possible causes? We're wondering if the load balancer is stripping the cookie but we have no evidence of this, just a gut feel

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710489/asp-net-forms-authentication-on-load-balanced-servers

Comment: Also, each server will need to have the same machine key.

Comment: Actually, the servers don't need the same machine key. The load balancer is configured for sticky sessions and so the machine is irrelevant. We have a number of multi-server installations using this software and all servers are set to autogenerate the machine key

Comment: I've looked at that question and it doesn't ell me anything I don't know - thanks for the suggestion, though

Comment: Can you post the headers (e.g. from Chrome/IE dev tools or Firebug) for when it sets the cookie and also for when it does/does not send it back?

Answer (score 0):

> We've noticed that when the site is viewed via HTTPS, the cookie is
>   there, the authentication type is forms. HOWEVER, when we browse
>   non-secure, the cookie is missing and the authentication type is not
>   set.

This happens when you have set the `requireSSL="true"` on the `<forms >` tag.

How ever you can try to declare the `domain="yourdomain.com"` in the `<forms >` tag, with out the subdomain `www.`, because this can affect the cookie.

So first try this

```
<forms name="ASPDNSFGUID" domain="yourdomain.com" loginUrl="SignIn.aspx" 
          timeout="525600" />
```

then try to see if you have set programmatically the requireSSL.

Comment: If you check the syntax of the forms tag I posted, you'll see that requiresssl is not present (defaults to false). Also, comparing the forms tag on this site with other sites behind load balancers in multi-server environments, it's exactly the same, and they work fine

Comment: @eggheaddesign Of cource I check it, how ever what you describe is done when this is set, or the domain is not match. This can be change programmatically or on upper level, maybe you do not have set, but something else is set it. After that, focus on domain name.

Comment: Thanks for your input. We've checked the code and nowhere is requiressl used at all

Comment: @eggheaddesign then try the `domain`

Comment: we've tried the domain and it made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: @eggheaddesign I left the answer as reference to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Is the cookie set on https, and if so, are https and http on the same domain but different only by protocol? ie https://www.somesite.com and http://www.somesite.com

Because, if they have a different subdomain you will have issues unless you specify domain="somesite.com" in your `<forms>` element in the web.config

Comment: Thanks for replying. HTTP and HTTPS are on the same domain, the only difference is protocol